# Can the Lie group $\text{G}_2$ be exhibited as an intersection $\text{SO}(7) \cap H$ where $H \leq \text{SL}_7(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

The compact simple Lie group $\text{G}_2$ has a well-known faithful representation on $\mathbb{R}^7$, so we can regard $\text{G}_2 \leq \text{GL}_7(\mathbb{R})$.  Equipping $\mathbb{R}^7$ with the usual euclidean inner product, it turns out that $\text{G}_2 \leq \text{SO}(7)$.

My question is that in the title: Can we write $\text{G}_2 = \text{SO}(7) \cap H$, where $H \neq \text{G}_2$ is also a subgroup of $\text{SL}_7(\mathbb{R})$?

I would be very happy to hear that the answer is "yes," but strongly suspect that the answer is "no."

Addendum: More generally, I'd be interested in learning the existence of connected Lie subgroups $K$ with $\text{G}_2 < K < \text{SL}_7(\mathbb{R})$ other than $K = \text{SO}(7)$.

Comment: As per Ted Shifrin's suggestion: [As I'm sure you already know](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39580980#39580980) (see the conversation above that message), some papers by Bryant might contain some relevant information. I have looked at *Submanifolds and Special Structures on the Octonians* which doesn't seem to have anything directly relevant, though a lot of related stuff ($G_2$ as a subgroup of Spin(7), for instance). There are probably many other relevant papers by Bryant. But, again, you probably already know about those papers.

Comment: @Danu: Thank you (and Ted Shifrin) for the suggestions.  But yes, I've read that paper already :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite a full answer, but it does answer your addendum (where you have added the word 'connected').

Under the action of $G_2$, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_7$ decomposes as $\mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus \mathbb{R}^7 \oplus S^2_0(\mathbb{R}^7)$. Now, $\mathfrak{so}(7) = \mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus \mathbb{R}^7,$ so the only candidates for $\mathfrak{h}$ are $\mathfrak{g}_2$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus S^2_0(\mathbb{R}^7).$ But $\mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus S^2_0(\mathbb{R}^7)$ is not closed under the Lie bracket. For example, $ [ E_{1,1} - E_{2,2}, E_{1,2}+E_{2,1} ] = 2 E_{1,2}-2 E_{2,1}$, which is not an element of $\mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus S^2_0(\mathbb{R}^7)$ (I'm using the standard definition of $G_2$ here of course). This shows that the identity component of $H$ is in fact $G_2$.

Comment: This basically does it, I think.  If there were an $H \leq \text{SL}_7(\mathbb{R})$ with $\text{G}_2 = \text{SO}(7) \cap H$, then of course $\text{G}_2 \leq H < \text{SL}_7(\mathbb{R})$.  Your argument shows that the identity component of $H$ is either $H^0 = \text{G}_2$ or $H^0 = \text{SO}(7)$, so $H$ is a disjoint union of copies of $\text{G}_2$ or copies of $\text{SO}(7)$.  Does that sound right?